# Could/should these these three queries be combined into one?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have these three steps to make a list of users that are in a group, but not in the current project:

1: Get all the users in the current Group:

```
List<ApplicationUser> allGroupUsers = await db.UsersInGroups
    .Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId)
    .Select(u => u.User)
    .ToListAsync();
```

2: Get all the users in the current Project:

```
List<ApplicationUser> projectUsers = await db.UsersInProjects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectId == id)
    .Select(u => u.User)
    .ToListAsync();
```

3: Make a list of Group users that are not in the Project:

```
List<ApplicationUser> availableUsers = allGroupUsers.Except(projectUsers).ToList();
```

These are all the relevant models:

```
public class UserInGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class UserInProject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public int? UserInGroupId { get; set; }
    public UserInGroup UserInGroup { get; set; } // Can only be in one group
    public List<UserInProject> UserInProjects { get; set; } // Can be in many projects
    // some more properties
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserInGroup> UsersInGroup { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    // some more properties
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public List<UserInProject> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
    // some more properties
}
```

Is it trivial to combine these three queries into one, saving one trip to the database, and making the code cleaner?

Comment: I would think that if you follow the single responsibility principle, you should leave them separate. However, you could have one query pull a list of users from the DB and then use linq to query that list in memory, thus faster and fewer db calls. Just my 2 cents though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
            List<ApplicationUser> availableUsers = await db.ApplicationUser
                .Include(u => u.UserInProjects)
                .Where(u => (u.UserInGroupId == groupId && !u.UserInProjects.Any(p => p.ProjectId == id)
                             || (u.UserInGroupId != groupId && u.UserInProjects.Any(p => p.ProjectId == id))))
                .ToListAsync();
```

so either get the users that are in that group, and not in project, or the other way around - not in group, but in a project

Comment: This solves the saving trips to the database part of the question, but it's really not easier to read. So I think I will keep the steps I already have after all.